# I want city to autocomplete but restrict the autocomplete results to multiple cities

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, autocomplete

I want to add google autocomplete but add multiple cities like this

```
function initiali() {
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
                /** @type {HTMLInputElement}*/
    (document.getElementById('autocomplete_add')),
    {
        types: ['geocode'],
        componentRestrictions: {country: ['us','In']}
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 
                                  'place_changed', 
                                  function() {fillInAddress();}
    );
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initiali);
```

But this is not working. Tell me some suggestion how should I  resolve this problem.

Comment: It's not working as in...? Exceptions? Errors? No result? Too many results?

Comment: this is not working . Means autocomplete is not showing any result